# Get YTD sum value

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

The first two columns work great but I do not know how to get the results for the third column. Please tell me how I can have the third column to show the year to date data with accordance to the week. Please provide assistance.

```
select "Builder","Traffic", sum(cast("Traffic" as int)) as YTD
from trafficdatapcr
where "Week" = '2016-12-11'
group by "Builder","Traffic"
```

The sample data:

```
     Week          Builder             Traffic

   2016-12-11      Macys                 100
   2016-10-11      Bloomingdales          15
   2016-08-11      Saks                   85
   2016-02-11      Cole Haan              95
   2015-12-25      Kroger                 65
```

My current results:

```
 Builder          Traffic        YTD
 Macys              100           100
```

The expected results:

```
 Builder          Traffic        YTD
 Macys              100          100
 Saks               0             85
 Bloomingdales      0             15
 Cole Haan          0             95
 Kroger             0             65
```

Comment: What is the Week?

Comment: Please add sample data and your expected results ;).

Comment: Please find the post edited above.

Comment: And where is your sample data?

Comment: Edited the post, thanks!!!

Comment: What data type is `"Week"` and `"Traffic"`? `'2016-12-11'` looks like it is intended to be a date, but why are you comparing that to a column named *Week*?

Comment: <"Week"> is timestamp and <"Traffic"> is varchar.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as a varchar?

Comment: Yup, do not what was going through my mind. Got that changed to integer. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause is eliminating the the records you desire, use a case to conditionally display the traffic for the desired week instead of the where clause

```
select "Builder"
     , case when "Week" = to_date('2016-12-11',YYYY-MM-DD') then "Traffic" else 0 end as "Traffic"
     , sum(cast("Traffic" as int)) as YTD
from trafficdatapcr
group by "Builder","Traffic"
Order by week Desc
```

It does seem odd though that if someone were to select 2016-10-11 the YTD would be all dates.... so perhaps you want to conditionally sum as well...

```
select "Builder"
     , case when "Week" = to_date('2016-12-11','YYYY-MM-DD') then "Traffic" else 0 end as "Traffic"
     , sum(case when "week"<=to_date('2016-12-11','YYYY-MM-DD') then cast("Traffic" as int) else 0 end) as YTD
from trafficdatapcr
group by "Builder","Traffic"
Order by week Desc
```

This way

- Macys will show as 0 0
- Bloomingdales would be 15 15

So 2nd query should return (assumign date of 2016-10-11) but in correct date order (don't know what order you want)

```
 Builder          Traffic        YTD
 Macys              0              0
 Saks               0             85
 Bloomingdales      15            15
 Cole Haan          0             95
 Kroger             0             65
```

Comment: @AQDeveloper yeah I caught that mistake and adjusted the date to 2016-10-11.

Comment: So do we need the second query statement then?

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  The 2nd query, assuming you want to still display all "dates" would have macy's listed as 0,0 while bloomingdales would be 15,15.  the conditional aggregration will only sum traffic if the date is on or before the date entered. The 1st query above should address the question, while the 2nd addresses what I would consider a logic flaw, we shouldn't display YTD totals unless it's on or before the week requested; but maybe you do.